# Why does popen not grab the output of qemu?

Tags: c, output, stdout, popen, qemu

This below code works for things like /bin/ls and other programs but not for qemu. How can i get the output stream of qemu with popen?
I ran `qemu-x86_64 -d cpu /bin/ls` and expected to get the same output as qemu but with a "read: "before it. When i run this i just just the normal qemu output in the console.

```c
int main()
{

        /* Call program */
        FILE* file = popen("/bin/ls", "r");
        if(file == NULL)
        {
            perror("popen");
            return 0;
        }

        /* output stream of program*/
        char *out = NULL;
        size_t outlen = 0;

        /*iterate through program output stream line by line */
        while (getline(&out, &outlen, file) >= 0) 
        {
            /* print output stream */
            printf("read: %s", out);
        }

        /* cleanup */
        pclose(file);
        free(out);
         
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Presumably, qemu doesn't write to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rici pointed out qemu actually does not print to `stdout`. Qemu prints to `stderr` and to redirect the output from `stderr` to `stdout` for popen to catch it i simply need to add `2>&1` behind the executed command.

So instead of running:

```c
FILE* file = popen("qemu-x86_64 -d cpu /bin/ls", "r");
```

I need to run:

```c
FILE* file = popen("qemu-x86_64 -d cpu /bin/ls 2>&1", "r");
```